# Set PATH when SSH into MacOS

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh

My problem is

```
$ ssh localhost fswatch          
bash: fswatch: command not found
```

when without SSH command (i.e. fswatch) works fine.

I found that PATH in SSH session is default Mac's

```
$ ssh localhost echo \$PATH        
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

since without SSH

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/kyb/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I really do not remember how have I set up the PATH, but sure `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` do not edit PATH variable. There is a config file `/etc/paths`:

```
$ cat /etc/paths         
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Homebrew, npm, pip usually install programs to `/usr/local/bin`, so all installed programs are there and I can't access them via `ssh localhost command` on my MacOS. There is no problem with Linux.

So my question is **how to configure OpenSSH to use PATHs from `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d?`**

I also tried to hack:

```
$ ssh localhost sh -lc 'echo empty;echo $PATH'

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
$ ssh localhost bash -lc 'echo empty;echo $PATH'

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

*first line is always empty, don't you know why?*

#### And my final workaround

```
$ ssh localhost bash -lc ':; 
    export PATH="$( cat /etc/paths /etc/paths.d/* | tr \\\\n : )"; 
    echo $PATH; 
    fswatch --version'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
fswatch 1.14.0
Copyright (C) 2013-2018 Enrico M. Crisostomo <enrico.m.crisostomo@gmail.com>.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Enrico M. Crisostomo.
```

*Here first `:;` is important because first command is somehow dropped from execution*

System: MacOS Mojave 10.14.5
`ssh -V`: `OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3`
`bash --version` `GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0)`

Comment: Try `su -l login -c ...` with your login name.

Comment: I am not clear what do you want different from your "final workaround".
Would an alias be enough?

Comment: No. I'd like to configure SSH server.

Comment: What happens when you do `ssh -t localhost fswatch` instead of `ssh localhost fswatch` ?

Comment: ```~ ❯❯❯ ssh localhost fswatch
bash: fswatch: command not found
~ ❯❯❯ ssh -t localhost fswatch
bash: fswatch: command not found
Connection to localhost closed.
~ ❯❯❯```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure the SSH server to give clients a customized environment, including a custom `PATH` variable. You will need to configure 2 things:

1. Create the file `~/.ssh/environment` on the server containing the following:

   ```
   PATH=/Users/kyb/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
   ```
2. Change the SSH server config file `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to include the following line:

   ```
   PermitUserEnvironment PATH,LANG
   ```

Finally, restart/reload the SSH daemon on the server. SSH login clients should have access to your customized environment!

Comment: This can have severe security implications, see ```man sshd_config``` -> PermitUserEnvironment

Comment: It is dangerous. So it would be better `PermitUserEnvironment PATH,LANG`

Answer (score 0):

On my system I can just edit `.bashrc` and put this *at the very top*:

```
PATH=/my/path:$PATH
```

It is important to put it before:

```
# If not running interactively, skip the rest
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Answer (score -2):

For my answer I assume you are using the Bourne Again SHell, but the following is true for most other shells as well:

The reason for the observed behavior is, that your command will not run in an interactive but a non-interactive shell:

> When the user's identity has been accepted by the server, the server
> either executes the given
> command in a non-interactive session or, if no command has been specified, logs into the machine
> and gives the user a normal shell as an interactive session.  All communication with the remote
> command or shell will be automatically encrypted.

- `$ man ssh`

I suspect that somewhere inside your `.bashrc` you extend your `PATH` variable. But BASH will not interpret your `.bashrc` file if you do not run an interactive shell:

> **When** an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
> reads and executes commands
> from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist.

- `$ man bash`

So the easiest solution to this problem is to just provide the full path to the executable, like: `$ ssh localhost /full/path/to/fswatch` This is the most stable and secure solution to this problem and will always work!

When you connect to `localhost` you can leverage the `which` command: `$ ssh localhost $(which fswatch)`. However, this will most probably not work, when you connect to another host.

Another, possible way would be to manipulate the `PATH` environment variable of the remote host for non-interactive shells (see @hedgie's answer). However, this poses security implications and therefore should not be used in production:

> Enabling environment processing may enable users to bypass
> access restrictions in some configurations using mechanisms such
> as LD_PRELOAD.

- `man sshd_config`

Comment: This will not work. `which` also relies on PATH.

Comment: @kyb: Nope. ```$(which ...)``` will run locally, even before the connection via ssh is being established. Read up https://manpages.debian.org/buster/bash/bash.1.en.html#Command_Substitution And for the third time: I do not recommend using ```which``` but using the full path to the executable. The which part is only an example to automate this, if you connect to localhost. If you connect to another location you cannot use which but have to manually provide the full path.

Comment: `ssh localhost which fish` returns nothing, but this `ssh localhost env PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/bin which fish` returns  `/usr/local/bin/fish`

Comment: Do not run ```ssh localhost which fish``` but ```ssh localhost $(which fish)``` !

Comment: Ahah ). What if I am connecting to remote host with different PATHs. I.e from linux to mac.

Comment: I extended my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: Too much text. And still I cannot see a solution. Sorry man. I have already read enough manuals. The real solution is to edit PATH in any way.